# Periodically get CPU usage for single process

Tags: ubuntu, ps, top, cpu-usage, watchdog

I've got a problem with the   `kswapd0` process (pid 52), which from time to time would start to use 25% of the cpu (one full core). I usually stop it with the command `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"` (see IBM's page about the problem, [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21665911)).

I'd like to set a watchdog, which would execute that command whenever kswapd0 keeps using 22%+ CPU for more than three seconds. Therefore I'd like to get kswapd0 cpu usage periodically, in an efficient manner.

---

Here are the commands I currently use to get the instant CPU usage:

I get the information from top:

```
top -bn1 -p $(pgrep kswapd0)
```

and I pipe the output to sed to extract the %CPU value from the last line:

```
... | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/^ *([^ ]+ +){8}([^ ]+)( +[^ ]+){3}/\2/'
```

---

I know that in interactive mode, the cpu usages displayed by `top` are the average cpu usages between two refreshes, but I don't know what it is when top is invoked a single time.

Note that `ps -p $PID -o %CPU` doesn't fit my problem since the average cpu usage it prints is done on the whole process lifetime (rather than the very last seconds).

How do I get the cpu usage with a lighter technique ? (a more appropriate one)

Comment: If you check the accumulated cpu time every so often , you could do your own math / determination

Comment: @loxaxs see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/how-do-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat. The bug is from 2014, if I was in your shoes I would consider OS fix.

Comment: `top` always only shows average cpu usage, that is jiffies/interval, cf. [How to calculate the CPU usage of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424556/196133)